# How ac coupling in scopes does not give you a phase shift? Or does it?

Tags: oscilloscope, high-pass-filter, filtering

For what i know, filtering something always gives some amount of phase shift.

So how do oscilloscopes with ac coupling don't have that? 
Do they correct in software? If so, how they used to do it at the time of analog scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is phase shift, that is sort of required by a causal filter!

The trick is that the pole is way below the lowest frequency you are likely to be interested in when using AC coupling (Think a few Hz) so the shift (and attenuation) start below anything you are much interested in.

The phase shift only really matters over the transition band anyway, as below the transition there is nothing much to see because the filter has attenuated it, and above the transition there is not much phase shift, so put the transition band down where nobody using AC coupling cares and call it good.

The dirty little secret is that all scopes lie to a greater or lesser extent, and you always need to do some interpretation of what you are seeing on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

> For what i know, filtering something always gives some amount of phase
>   shift.

Correct

> So how do oscilloscopes with ac coupling don't have that?

They do have that - the filter is just a lowish frequency high pass RC network and, like all other filters of that type, it will give a phase shift as the lower frequencies are approached, as should be expected.

Connect a signal generator into both/two inputs and have one input AC coupled and see for yourself.